# Не сохраняет логи в файл log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Создал MVC проект в IDEA, подключил через pom.xml log4j, доюбавил простое логиерование но в файл не записывает:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>log4jteach</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4jteach</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

***src/main/java/OrderLogic.class :***

```
public class OrderLogic{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(OrderLogic.class));

    public void doOrder(){
        System.out.println("Заказ оформлен");
        log.info("Заказ оформлен. Это информационное сообщение.");
        addToCard();
    }

    private void addToCard() {
        System.out.println("Товар добавлене в корзину");
        log.warning("Это сообщение ошибки (походу)");
    }
}
```

***src/main/java/test.class***

```
public class test {
    public static OrderLogic logic;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logic = new OrderLogic();
        logic.doOrder();
    }
}
```

***src/main/resourses/log4j.properties***

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Вы забыли задать вопрос в своем вопросе.

Comment: Надеюсь, права на запись файла имеются...

Answer (score 1):

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
```

замени на

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs/myapp.log
```